# PowerShell function return type not as expected

Tags: function, powershell, casting

I have a script that accepts a string parameter :

```
script-that-takes-string-param.ps1 

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="path")]
    [string]$path,
)
```

And I have another script that calls the first script :

```
parent-script.ps1 

function CreateDir($dir) {
    if (!(Test-Path $dir)) {
        mkdir $dir
    }
}

function CreatePath($BaseDir, $Environment, $Site, $Domain){     
    $path = [string]::format("{0}{1}\{2}\{3}", $BaseDir, $Environment, $Site, $Domain)
    CreateDir $path
    $path
}

$path = CreatePath 'c:\web\' 'qa' 'site1' 'com'

.\script-that-takes-string-param.ps1 -path $path
```

Running this script throws the exception :

```
"Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'path'. Cannot convert value to type System.String"
```

Casting the parameter doesn't work :

```
.\script-that-takes-string-param.ps1 -path [string] $path
```

And casting the function result doesn't work either :

```
$path = [string] CreatePath 'global' 'site1'
```

But what is really strange is that if I run `parent-script.ps1` twice from the PS command line, the 1st time it throws exceptions, but the 2nd time it executes with no errors.

Comment: Call `GetType` on `$path` before passing it off to script-that-takes-string-param and see what the type is.  Maybe you're accidentally changing its type to something and not realizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing "return". Output that is not saved to a variable is automatically returned. It shouldn't do any difference but it won't hurt to try.

Can you provide a full exception? Without seing the complete exception I get the feeling that the error is caused by something inside your script(ex. a function).

**EDIT** Your `mkdir` is causing the problem. When you run it, it returns an object representing the created directory(a `DirectoryInfo` object if I remember correctly). To fix this, try:

```
function CreateDir($dir) {
    if (!(Test-Path $dir)) {
        mkdir $dir | out-null
    }
}
```

or combine them like:

```
function CreatePath($BaseDir, $Environment, $Site, $Domain){     
    $path = [string]::format("{0}{1}\{2}\{3}", $BaseDir, $Environment, $Site, $Domain)

    if(!(Test-Path $path -PathType Container)) {
        New-Item $path -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }

    $path
}
```

Comment: Ok, but is the function return type affected by how the output is returned ?

Comment: It shouldn't, but as said, it won't hurt to try. Sometimes weird things happends. More importantly. Provide the full exception in your question(like I've asked for in my answer) :-)

Comment: Ok I modified my original question to more fully represent the actual code (not possible to post the actual code for many reasons).  I also included the full text of the exception.

Comment: It's still not enough. We need details about the hidden parts. Not your sensitive information, but what is done. Ex. do you in any part of the code ouput anything(like using `$variable` or another function that isn't stored in a variable) ?

Comment: Ok I revised to include all the relevant code.  No, nothing is output.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !  So in PS every returned object that is not assigned to a local variable or $null is sent to standard out ?

Comment: Yes, unless they wrote the output using `Write-Host` (which is unusual). `mkdir` (`New-Item`) however, uses the normal `WriteObject` (binary version of `Write-Output` or `$obj`).

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that your

```
#do some other stuff with $path
```

writes something to the standard output, causing the function to return an array that contains said output and the path you expect. Can you send details on what you do in that bit?

Comment: Ok I revised to include all the relevant code.  No, nothing is output.

Comment: There you are :)
`mkdir <some path>`
returns an object corresponding to the folder you just created. This object is sent to the standard output, alongside your return value ($path).

This also explains why the second execution works. The second time, the folder is already present so mkdir is not executed, and only $path is sent to the standard output.

Comment: My bad, forgot to include the solution :p  
Just add `$null =`in front of mkdir. This'll send the output of mkdir to the trash.  
In other words:  
`$null = mkdir $dir`

Comment: Thanks for the solution !  I'm assuming since both you and @Graimer noticed it immediately once I'd posted complete code , this is a common PS problem ?

Comment: Yes it is. You need to be very careful about what goes into the pipe when attempting to create functions as you would do in other languages. Take a look at this [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/10/use-the-pipeline-to-create-robust-powershell-functions.aspx), that may give you more understanding about this behavior.